# Could I prove this coset theorem using just homomorphism like following?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

In Dummit's Abstract Algebra, there is this Proposition 3.4 in page 80:

[image]

If there is some homomorphism from G to H as following:

[image]

Could I prove it by using only that homomorphism as following?

That homomorphism would bring $u$, $v$, $n$, and $m$ to exactly only one element in the codomain H: $U$, $V$, $N$, and $N$ respectively (otherwise it's not a function). So $UN = VN$ is only when $U = V$. As homomorphism only brings any values from domain to exactly only one value in codomain, uN = vN is only when u and v are in the same fiber of homomorphism. I said in the same fiber because also note that in my proof the set of elements of fiber above N is even not necessarily a subgroup of $G$. Where am I wrong?

Comment: Which homomorphism are you talking about? Note that $N$ is not assumed to be normal.

Comment: What homomorphism?

Comment: @Berci I have added the homomorphism in my question, may you see it again? Also by homomorphism, the set of elements in fiber N is not necessarily a group.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft I have added the homomorphism in my question, may you see it again? Also by homomorphism, the set of elements in fiber N is not necessarily a group.

Comment: The addition does not really make sense. Where did $H$ come from? And the last part of your comment seems irrelevant.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft The fibers of the homomorphism are the fibers above elements of H.

Comment: I am fully aware of what fibers are and what they look like for homomorphisms.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Oh, sorry. May you elaborate more why it doesn't make sense?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101946/discussion-between-ari-royce-hidayat-and-tobias-kildetoft).

Comment: With group homomorphisms, the preimage of the identity is always a normal subgroup. But $N$ is not assumed to be normal. If $N$ is not normal, then because it contains the identity, it would have to be mapped to the identity by $\varphi$, which in turn implies that $N$ is normal, in contradiction to the assumption that it isn't.

Comment: @celtschk But even the proof in my question doesn’t assume N is a group?

Comment: To define a homomorphism $\phi$ you need to tell us what $\phi(g)$ is for any given $g$. Drawing lines and dots is not helpful.

Comment: @AriRoyceHidayat: You assumed that $\phi$ is a homomorphism. That **implies** that the preimage of the identity under is a normal subgroup. Since the statement to prove only demands $N$ to be a subgroup, not a normal subgroup, there will in general not **exist** a homomorphism that has $N$ as fiber.

Comment: @celtschk That’s exactly my question where I am wrong. In my proof, I don’t even need that N to be a subgroup, it could be just any fibers of some homomorphism. I also just read answer from AnalysisStudent0414, but please be noted the proposition is just to prove that cosets partition G, not to prove that $uN \\ vN$ is well defined yet.

Comment: I did not talk about "well-defined" at all. The end point is that the left cosets partition does not inherit a group structure from $G$ unless $N$ is normal, and, well, before  thinking about having a homomorphism we should have two **groups**.

Comment: @AriRoyceHidayat: Please read my statement **carefully.** The logical connection is the other way round. If $\phi$ is a homomorphism, then $N$ must be a normal subgroup. In other words, you *do* have the subgroup condition in your proof, it's just hidden in the word “homomorphism”.

Comment: @celtschk Yes, but in my proof, N is not even necesarily a subgroup, it could be just well with any fibers. And that’s exactly my question: to prove $uN = vN$ iif they are in the same fiber, is N necesarily a subgroup? As in my proof it seems not.

Answer (score 3):

I think you want to define a homomorphism $\phi: G \to \{\text{left cosets of }N \text{ in }G\}$, by saying that given an element $g \in G$ you can write $g= un$, for some $u \in G \setminus N$ and $n \in N$ and then define $\phi(g)=u$.

This works whenever $N$ is normal, it is the standard surjective map $\pi: G \to G/N$. However, it never works when $N$ is not normal (as celtschk pointed out in the comments, you can actually prove that $N$ is normal when you have such a homomorphism, since $N = \phi^{-1}(1)$).

The reason it does not work is because multiplication fails: the left cosets partition is **not a group** (at least not with a structure inherited from $G$). In fact, given $g=u_g n_g$, $h= u_h n_h$ then it is not true in general that $gh$ is in the $u_gu_h$ coset!
Write
$$u_g n_g u_h n_h = u_g u_h u_h^{-1} n_g u_h n_h = u_g u_h (u_h^{-1} n_g u_h) n_h$$
Now if this element were in the $u_g u_h$ coset you'd have $u_h^{-1}n_gu_h \in N$, which holds when $N$ is normal, but not in general.

In a nutshell, the left cosets partition is not well-behaved with respect to the group operation unless $N$ is normal, which is why you only have a group structure (and also a homomorphism, which is not hard to prove once you know the above) when $N$ is normal.

Comment: Sorry, but homomorphism is already assumed by using it in my proof. Also the proposition is just used to prove that cosets are partition G, not to prove that $uN \\ vN$ is well defined yet (that needs N to be normal). My confusion is it seems that in my proof I could show that $uN = vN$ iif $u$ and $v$ are in the same coset, even without requiring N to be a subgroup at all.

Comment: If you assume that $\phi$ is a homomorphism, this implies that $N$ is normal. So  you get a contradiction when $N$ is not normal, which implies that $\phi$ is not a homomorphism. The problem is actually deeper: what is the group structure on the left cosets group?

Comment: No, no. Left cosets are defined for any subgroup of $G$, but their set does not inherit a group structure unless said subgroup is normal.

Comment: Sorry there’s some confusion because I use the term coset incorrectly. Yes in homomorphism $N$ must be a normal subgroup, but in my proof I could just pick any fibers (not normal, not subgroup) say it is $M$, and work it out to show that $uM = vM$ iif u and v are in the same fiber so it also partitions G, is it correct?

Comment: I don't know, the correctness really depends on that "work it out" part.

Answer (score 2):

Let's write $u\sim v$ iff $u\in vN$.
There indeed exists a canonical *function* $\varphi:G\to G/\sim$ with fibers exactly the left cosets, but

1. In order to establish the quotient set $G/\sim$ we should *already know* that $\sim$ is an equivalence relation, which is basically the claim of this proposition.
2. We will get a group structure on $G/\sim$ iff $N$ is a *normal subgroup*, which means that the left and right cosets coincide. (Observe e.g. that taking elementwise inverses, we obtain $(gN)^{-1}=N^{-1}g^{-1}=Ng^{-1}$.)
   In this case, $\varphi$ will be indeed a homomorphism. 
   But this is not required for proving that $\sim$ is an equivalence relation.

---

Note also, that for any *subset* $N$ of $G$, we have the following facts about the relation $\sim$ defined above:

1. $\sim$ is reflexive iff $1\in N$ (where $1$ denotes the identity element of $G$).
2. $\sim$ is symmetric iff $N$ is closed under inverses ($x\in N\implies x^{-1}\in N$).
3. $\sim$ is transitive iff $N$ is closed under multiplication ($x, y\in N\implies xy\in N$).